# Tensor product definition of connections for vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry

I am self studying differential geometry and I am trying to understand this definition:
[image]

So I don't have much experience working with tensor products. I just know the universal property characterization, but why is the tensor product definition given in the last part equivalent to the Leibniz rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $s$ is a section of the vector bundle $E$ and if $f$ is a smooth function on $M$, $s\otimes df$ is the $E$-valued $1$-form defined by
$$
\forall p\in M,\forall v\in T_pM,\quad \left(s \otimes df\right)_p(v) = df_p(v)s_p.
$$
You can think of it as a $1$-form with coefficients in $E$.
You could have guessed it from the the equality on the line above, where clearly, it corresponds to the term $(Xf)s$ for $s$ a vector field.
Indeed, $(Xf)s = df(X)s$ is the function $p\mapsto df_p(X_p)s_p$.